# Aquaris m10 bricked!

Tags: ubuntu-touch, bq, aquaris, m10

I was trying to update to OTA-11 a few days ago.  Everything seemed to go fine, but when I restarted, all I got was the Ubuntu splash screen and those 4 blinking dots.  I left it over night... nothing.  I tried rebooting... nothing.  I got desperate, and downloaded the software from bq to re-flash it (frieza image, and sp flash-tools), and I can't get it to work.  I installed the drivers in windows, and after several attempts, got the program to start.  It seems to recognize that my tablet is connected.  The tablet reboots repeatedly, but not into fastboot.  Eventually it turns itself off, and I get a port error message.
My hope is that there is a command-line solution through ubuntu, or someone can explain sp flash-tools.